# How to change font output in textfields via Keyboard extension in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, custom-keyboard

I'm setting up a keyboard extension for iOS and would like for the output of the keyboard into text fields in 3rd party apps like Instagram (and other apps) to be the font "Typewriter". How do I go about doing this?

I see that this app keyboard extension was able to solve this problem https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fonts/id1454061614

This is a new iOS keyboard extension and was able to get the font inside the app and change the keyboard GUI to be the typewriter font, but not the output inside of 3rd part apps

I expect the output to be Typewriter font inside text fields in 3rd party apps